# Javascript array loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Is it possible to loop through the array like this.
I think I need to change the order of the array data.

**Array:**

```
var cars = [];

cars.push(["Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover"]);
cars.push([22, 15, 5, 17]);
cars.push([18, 13, 2, 15]);

var arrayLength = cars.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
 document.write(cars[0] + ' - ' + cars[1] + ' - ' + cars[2]);
}
```

**Result**

Volvo - 22 - 18

BMW - 15 - 13

Saab - 5 - 2

Land Rover - 17 - 15

Comment: A small remark, should you not objectify it ? Then it would allow you to manage your data more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You mind find it more useful to reorganise your data into something more meaningful. Here I've used an object:

```
var cars = {
  'Volvo': [22, 18],
  'BMW': [15, 13],
  'Saab': [5, 2],
  'Land Rover': [17, 15]
}

for (var p in cars) {
  console.log(p + ' - ' + cars[p].join(' - '));
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Volvo - 22 - 18
BMW - 15 - 13
Saab - 5 - 2
Land Rover - 17 - 15
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/0Lgznf1p/)

Answer (score 0):

you are looping through but using hard-coded indexes...

[@NinaScholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) answer is correct, but I would take it further so you're not depending on the array size:

```js
var cars = [];

cars.push(["Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover"]);
cars.push([22, 15, 5, 17]);
cars.push([18, 13, 2, 15]);

var arrayLength = cars.length, // will output 3
    carsLength = cars[0].length; // will output 4
  
for (var iCar = 0; iCar < carsLength; iCar++) {
  var carLine = []; // to hold all values for this car
    
  for(var iSize = 0; iSize < arrayLength; iSize++) {
    // add all values for this car
    carLine.push(cars[iSize][iCar]); 
  }

  // print it by joining all car values
  document.write(carLine.join(' - ') + '<br/>');
}
```

This way you are not bound to the size of the array... for example, you can easily have it like:

```
cars.push(["Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover", "Mercedes"]);
cars.push([22, 15, 5, 17, 22, 32]);
cars.push([18, 13, 2, 15, 4, 5]);
```

and the code will work flawlessly.

Also, a improvement would be to add the array sorting into it's own function and call the function instead, like:

```
function getCarsWithFeatures(arr) {

    var arrayLength = cars.length, // will output 3
        carsLength = cars[0].length, // will output 4
        allCars = [];

    for (var iCar = 0; iCar < carsLength; iCar++) {
      var carLine = []; // to hold all values for this car

      for(var iSize = 0; iSize < arrayLength; iSize++) {
        // add all values for this car
        carLine.push(cars[iSize][iCar]); 
      }

      // print it by joining all car values
      allCars.push( carLine.join(' - ') );
    }

    return allCars;
}
```

and then you can easily have:

```
var cars = [];

cars.push(["Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover", "Mercedes", "Audi"]);
cars.push([22, 15, 5, 17, 22, 32]);
cars.push([18, 13, 2, 15, 4, 5]);

var allCars = getCarsWithFeatures(cars);

for(var i = 0; i < allCars.length; i++)
    document.write( allCars[i] + '<br/>' );
```

**Note:** When writing code, try to write it in a way that you don't repeat yourself and it's extensible if the "source" changes...

Answer (score 0):

This is what a "**zip**" function can help with. Example using **lodash** library

```
var tuples = _.zip(cars[0], cars[1], cars[2]);
```

Then to format as required:

```
tuples.forEach(function (tuple) {
  document.write(tuple.join(' - ') + ' <br/>')
});
```

You could simply include lodash (depending on how you are handling your dependencies):

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arrays have a fixed size, you can use [array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this:

```js
var cars = [];

cars.push(["Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover"]);
cars.push([22, 15, 5, 17]);
cars.push([18, 13, 2, 15]);

var res = cars.reduce(function (a, b) {
     return [a[0] + " - " + b[0], a[1] + " - " + b[1], a[2] + " - " + b[2]];
});

document.write(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Check the snippet below, please

```js
var cars = [];

cars.push(["Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover"]);
cars.push([22, 15, 5, 17]);
cars.push([18, 13, 2, 15]);

var arrayLength = cars[0].length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
 document.write(cars[0][i] + ' - ' + cars[1][i] + ' - ' + cars[2][i] + '<br>');
}
```